# delete rows from multiple tables in sql server with join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find a way to delete a row from multiple tables in SQL server using join, I cannot execute like the following

```
delete T1,T2 
from Rendezvous t1 join CFRendezvous T2 
on SUBSTRING(T1.RK_PI_TO_CFREDZ,9,LEN(T1.RK_PI_TOCFREDZ)) = T2.CASEFOLDERID 
where WFSTATE != 100
```

is there an alternative way to do that in SQLserver?

Comment: Hint: `ON DELETE CASCADE`

Comment: @Sami I cannot alter the table

Comment: You need 2 deletes, one for each table.

Comment: @AIMadi You can't do that using one statement. You could use [`OUTPUT Clause`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to get the `Id`s from the first `DELETE` and then delete from the second table.